# OledbDriver doing case insensitive LIKE

Tags: .net, oledb

I am **using excel as a database**. I am searching through it using a query. I am using `LIKE` from SQL. I would like to search ignoring the case.

When I try following

`...LOWER([COLUMN_NAME]) LIKE "%query%"` It throws me the error as `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).`

When I use `[LOWER(COLUMN_NAME)] LIKE "%query%"` It gives error as `No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Can somebody point me to right syntax to use for case insensitive searching ..

Comment: What's the backend database? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Doh! You did say. I even read it. Blast. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your quoted code is:

```
LOWER([COLUMN_NAME]) LIKE "%query%"
```

Those double quotes should probably be single quotes:

```
LOWER([COLUMN_NAME]) LIKE '%query%'
```

**Edit**: I just tried it, and indeed the double quotes caused me to get a similar error to yours. With single quotes, as far as I can tell it doesn't like the use of the function. However, it appears (at least in my case) to be case-insensitive anyway if I just do:

```
...COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%pattern%'
```

This is Excel 2007 on Windows XP. I could **not** find a reference telling me that that behavior was guaranteed, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Access 2013 on Windows 7 here and LIKE %..% appears to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of work with excel and to query the data I find this super useful:

http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2008/01/linq-to-excel-provider-25.html

Comment: `Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.` 